# Update @FocusState in UIHostingConfiguration

Tags: swift, swiftui, ios16

I'm working with new feature in iOS 16: UIHostingConfiguration. In a content view I put a TextField. I try to manage the TextField's focus. To do that, I've created a @FocusState var. Unfortunately, I can't update .wrappedValue - the wrapped value always is false. Here's my code:

Cell:

```
cell.configurationUpdateHandler = { [self] (cell, state) in
      cell.contentConfiguration = UIHostingConfiguration {
          TaskView(task: task, shouldFocus: focusedTask == task)
      }
}
```

View:

```
struct TaskView: View {

@ObservedObject var task: Task
@FocusState var shouldFocus: Bool

init(task: Task, shouldFocus: Bool) {
    self.task = task
    self.$shouldFocus.wrappedValue = shouldFocus
    print($shouldFocus)
}

var body: some View {
    
   HStack() {
       
       Button("END") {
           $shouldFocus.wrappedValue = false
       }
       
        TextField("Task", text: $task.title)
           .focused($shouldFocus)
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I reported this issue to the Apple Feedback Assistance, and they let me know the issue probably was resolved on iOS 16.1. I have verified that, and it works.

Answer (score 1):

The `FocusState` does not work that way, it is like `State` but does not have init with initial value, so possible approach is as follows:

```
struct TaskView: View {
    @ObservedObject var task: Task

    var shouldFocus: Bool                   // << interface
    @FocusState private var inFocus: Bool   // << internal 

    init(task: Task, shouldFocus: Bool) {
        self.task = task
        self.shouldFocus = shouldFocus
    }

    var body: some View {

        HStack() {

            Button("END") {
                inFocus = false
            }

            TextField("Task", text: $task.title)
                .focused($inFocus)
        }
        .onAppear {
            self.inFocus = shouldFocus  // << here !!
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you but it still doesn't work. It seems that TextField doesn't respond for the variable in .focused(). What's more, when I set self.inFocus to true and print value in the .onAppear method, it returns false. I thought about problem with UIHostingConfiguration and the .focused method so I've aksed about this issue on Apple Developer Forums but I got response that the .foucsed method works well in UIHostingConfiguration...

Comment: The issue might originate from some other code or conflict. Would you prepare minimal reproducible example or give a link to where this code is located?

Comment: Of course. Here's a link: [Xcode project](https://www.dropbox.com/s/h4ykym3kxc0zz6p/UIHostingConfigurationWithTextField%202.zip?dl=0). I've put the project on Dropbox.

Comment: For now I'd say it is bridge bug or ... they did not finish it to work with diffable data sources.